# Merging two files using AWK while changing primary key

Tags: awk

I am a beginner so apologies if this has been covered before, but I can't seem to find exactly what I need to solve this problem.

I am attempting to merge two files with multiple data and editing the primary key in the process using AWK.

```
$ awk –f convert.awk File1 File2 > output
```

File 1 :

```
# node index, x-coord, y-coord, z-coord
MESHPOINT_COORDINATES
  1 0.40157080 0.01165580 0.00000000
  2 5.33646366 -2.00531643 0.00000000
  3 4.16797174 2.29403052 0.00000000
  4 5.41856053 1.77526867 0.00000000
  5 4.29752634 6.05020186 0.00000000
  6 5.54741904 5.46307875 0.00000000
  7 5.13640734 9.99623421 0.00000000
  8 -4.66339121 2.00580631 0.00000000
  9 -0.83190475 4.30646155 0.00000000
 10 -2.08191023 4.82606149 0.00000000

NODES_TRIANG1
  1 188 28 27
  2 259 71 11
  3 31 4 30
  4 45 6 44
  5 396 40 39
  6 277 227 241
  7 194 113 112
  8 249 125 124
  9 168 114 113
 10 144 19 18
```

File 2:

```
# node index, x-coord, y-coord, z-coord
MESHPOINT_COORDINATES
1  9.81601843  1.04888344  0.0
2  8.31348347  0.78329398  0.0
3  8.33745723  1.45922849  0.0
4  8.37867147  1.40693006  0.0
5  8.37033787  0.88985348  0.0

NODES_TRIANG1
1  2048  2041  1964
2  381  1072  64
3  381  380  1072
4  234  394  393
5  1978  1739  1753
```

Desired output:

```
MESHPOINT_COORDINATES
 1 0.40157080 0.01165580 0.00000000
 2 5.33646366 -2.00531643 0.00000000
 3 4.16797174 2.29403052 0.00000000
 4 5.41856053 1.77526867 0.00000000
 5 4.29752634 6.05020186 0.00000000
 6 5.54741904 5.46307875 0.00000000
 7 5.13640734 9.99623421 0.00000000
 8 -4.66339121 2.00580631 0.00000000
 9 -0.83190475 4.30646155 0.00000000
 10 -2.08191023 4.82606149 0.00000000
 11 9.81601843 1.04888344 0.0
 12 8.31348347 0.78329398 0.0
 13 8.33745723 1.45922849 0.0
 14 8.37867147 1.40693006 0.0
 15 8.37033787 0.88985348 0.0

NODES_TRIANG1
1 188 28 27
2 259 71 11
3 31 4 30
4 45 6 44
5 396 40 39
6 277 227 241
7 194 113 112
8 249 125 124
9 168 114 113
10 144 19 18
11 2048 2041 1964
12 381 1072 64
13 381 380 1072
14 234 394 393
15 1978 1739 1753
```

The first data in both MESHPOINT_COORDINATES and NODES_TRIANG1 is the node index which works as a primary key so it can't be multiplied.

Is there any way to do this using AWK ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for showing efforts and samples,keep it up. For samples could you please remove `...` to make it clear, just post simple samples in text form and let us  know.

Comment: Thank You for your answer i edited it to the first 10 and first 5 rows of the files

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. Do you also want us to update the nodes in the triangles or just the triangle numbers? If you merge two files with two meshes, then you also need to update the vertice numbers which you use for building the triangles.

Comment: Thanks for the question , sorry im a bit late to answer. Yes i needed to update them too. I managed to do it myself, i didn't wanted you guys to do all the work for me. I appreciate your intent to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{m="MESHPOINT_COORDINATES"; n="NODES_TRIANG1"} 
    $1!="#" && NF>0 {
        if ($1==m) {status=1; next}; 
        if ($1==n) {status=2; next}; 
        if (status==1) {i1++; t1[i1]=$2" "$3" "$4}; 
        if (status==2) {i2++; t2[i2]=$2" "$3" "$4}
    }
    END{
        print m; for (i=1; i<=i1; i++) print i, t1[i]; print ""; 
        print n; for (i=1; i<=i2; i++) print i, t2[i]
    }' File1 File2
```

You can paste it to a file and make it easier to read. Ask questions, if something is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem it works perfectly, it would take ages to figure it out by myself.

Comment: Maybe you can add some newlines to your one-liner to make it easier to read here, or just write it as a script?